# ODBC connection to Sybase SQL Anywhere database

Tags: qgis

I have my GIS data in ESRI personal geodatabase, and my attributes in a Sybase SQL Anywhere database. 
I would like to make a join between my GIS data and my tabular data, but don't understand how to set up the correct ODBC connection. (I allready have the correct ODBC/OLE DB connection, Nordata, which works good in ArcMap), but how to use this connection in QGIS is my problem.

Which parameters should I use in this QGIS form for adding Vector layer

Or - maybe it is not possible to establish a ODBC connction to Sybase SQL Anywhere ver. 5.0?